# Realm objects containing arrays of each other on iOS

Tags: ios, realm

I have two objects, for example

```
Human
Man
```

They contain property of RLMArray that contains other type. But I can't get this to compile since headers conflict and obscure errors. I understand that they need to know about each other at the same time, but they can't.

My Human class:

```
#import "Man.h"

@interface Human : RLMObject
@property RLMArray <Man *><Man> *children;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Human)
```

Man class:

```
#import "Human.h"

@interface Man : RLMObject
@property RLMArray <Human *><Human> *children;
@end

RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Man)
```

How do I solve this? I'm getting unknown type: Human or Man. If I use the `@class Man` forward declaration for example and link the header in .m, then it says that "Cannot find protocol declaration for Man"

Answer (score 0):

I just did some testing for this. A forward class declaration of `Man` class should work, as long as you declare the `RLM_ARRAY_TYPE` protocol as well, and remove the generics declaration.

Human class:

```
@class Man;
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Man)

@interface Human : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Man> *children;
@end
```

Man class:

```
@class Human;
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Human)

@interface Man : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<Human> *children;
@end
```

Not a great solution, but hopefully that'll work for your needs.

That all being said, depending on your needs, a much nicer solution is to use Realm's [`RLMLinkingObjects` feature](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#inverse-relationships) to automatically set up the inverse relationship between these two objects.